# Pass a variable from next.js middleware to api req

Tags: typescript, api, request, next.js, middleware

I'm trying to pass a middleware variable to my API pages through "req" but it's not working

I tried to send user token to pages using the "req", but it always returns `null`

my middleware: `pages/api/users/_middleware.ts`

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getAccessToken } from '@lib/auth';

declare module 'next/server' {
  interface NextRequest {
    token: string;
  }
}

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const [, token] = await getAccessToken(req.headers.get('authorization'));
    req.token = token;
    return NextResponse.next();
  } catch(e) {
    const err = e as Error;
    const errorPayload = {
      error: 'unauthorized',
      error_message: err.message,
    };
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify(errorPayload),
      { status: 401 },
    );
  }
}
```

my api page that i tried to get the user token from req: `pages/api/users/[userId].ts`

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { UserModel } from '@database/models';

declare module 'next' {
  interface NextApiRequest {
    token: string;
  }
}

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const user = await UserModel.findOne({ token: req.token });
  
  res.status(200).send({
    success: true,
    user,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with next.js middleware as of now. If you used express middleware, it is possible with `res.locals`

> res.locals
>
> An object that contains response local variables scoped to
> the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered
> during that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this
> property is identical to app.locals.
>
> This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as
> the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and so on.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});
```

next.js middleware has no `res`, adding local variables directly on the request object is not supported. This is wrong:

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {}
```

next.js middleware takes `req` and `ev`

```
export default async function handler(req,ev) {

     console.log({req,ev})
}
```